# Linker error for running Opengl C++ in mac

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, opengl

I keep getting this error while compiling my code:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>    "_glewInit", referenced from:
>        _main in main.o
>    "_glfwCreateWindow", referenced from:
>        _main in main.o
>    "_glfwGetKey", referenced from:
>        _main in main.o
>    "_glfwInit", referenced from:
>        _main in main.o
>    "_glfwMakeContextCurrent", referenced from:
>        _main in main.o
>    "_glfwPollEvents", referenced from:
>        _main in main.o
>    "_glfwSetInputMode", referenced from:
>        _main in main.o
>    "_glfwSwapBuffers", referenced from:
>        _main in main.o
>    "_glfwTerminate", referenced from:
>        _main in main.o
>    "_glfwWindowHint", referenced from:
>        _main in main.o
>    "_glfwWindowShouldClose", referenced from:
>        _main in main.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I tried compiling it with both Xcode and terminal. I use the following command for compiling it with terminal:

```
$g++ -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/local/include -I/opt/local/include -L/usr/local/lib/ -L/opt/local/lib -lSOIL -framework GLUT -framework OpenGL -framework CoreFoundation -w -o main tutorial01.cpp
```

I have also tried everything many methods from stack overflow. But I am still open to retry any of them (maybe the order of trying them can change the result)

My code is attached. It is a very simple code for opening a window in opengl.

```
// Include standard headers
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Include GLEW
#include <GL/glew.h>

// Include GLFW
#include <glfw3.h>

GLFWwindow* window;

// Include GLM
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
using namespace glm;

int main( void )
{
    // Initialise GLFW
    if( !glfwInit() )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Failed to initialize GLFW\n" );
        getchar();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE); // To make MacOS happy; should not be needed
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    // Open a window and create its OpenGL context
    window = glfwCreateWindow( 1024, 768, "Tutorial 01", NULL, NULL);
    if( window == NULL ){
        fprintf( stderr, "Failed to open GLFW window. If you have an Intel GPU, they are not 3.3 compatible. Try the 2.1 version of the tutorials.\n" );
        getchar();
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    // Initialize GLEW
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLEW\n");
        getchar();
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    // Ensure we can capture the escape key being pressed below
    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GL_TRUE);

    // Dark blue background
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.4f, 0.0f);

    do{
        // Clear the screen. It's not mentioned before Tutorial 02, but it can cause flickering, so it's there nonetheless.
        glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

        // Draw nothing, see you in tutorial 2 !


        // Swap buffers
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();

    } // Check if the ESC key was pressed or the window was closed
    while( glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE ) != GLFW_PRESS &&
          glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == 0 );

    // Close OpenGL window and terminate GLFW
    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why 'g++' if you want to use clang?

Comment: The error is what I get using XCode. I really don't have any preference over them.

Comment: Do you have xcode set to link with the OpenGL.framework and GLUT.framework (something in the "Build Phases" tab)?

Comment: Yes. and I also added cocoa.framework due to some posts on stack overflow.

Comment: What symbol(s) are not found? They should normally be listed right after the error message you quoted.

Comment: I edited the post.